# Translate a CASE in Hive SQL to Python 3.6 IF else statment

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, hiveql

I'm trying to strip all the extensions from a column that hold product SKU.
The length is not constant. 
The only rule is that there are three hyphens, for example:
101-090-7612-02
In practice, some extensions start with a fourth hyphen and other with an underline
for example:
101-090-7612-02_love
101-090-762-02-T

I was able to achieve it with Hive SQL:

```
(CASE WHEN sku RLIKE '_'
  THEN split(sku ,'[\_]')[0]
  ELSE concat(split(sku ,'[\-]')[0],'-',split(sku ,'[\-]')[1],
   '-',split(sku ,'[\-]')[2],'-',split(sku ,'[\-]')[3])
  END) AS new_sku
```

afterward, I can GROUP BY new_sku and get all aggregated metrics, like sales, avg sale price, etc.

Of course i'll to .apply() a function on the dataFrame ...

...Now I want to get this CASE into Python 3.

Many Thanks for any Help!

Comment: what do you mean by python 3? you mean pyspark?

Comment: Hi Gaurann. My aim is to use it in a pandas DataFrame. I'm trying to do it in as a function or a lambda and .apply() it to the column. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a python function which remove the unwanted character and apply that function on dataframe.

```
d = {
    'sku': ["101-090-762-02-T", "101-090-7612-02_love"]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df
new_df = df.applymap(lambda sku: "-".join(sku.split("_")[:-1]) if len(sku.split("-")) == 3 else "-".join(sku.split("-")[:-1]))
print new_df
```

you can create a function to handle this and call that function as well.

```
def remove_ext(sku):
    temp = sku.split("-")
    return "-".join(sku.split("_")[:-1]) if len(temp) == 3 else "-".join(temp[:-1])


d = {
    'sku': ["101-090-762-02-T", "101-090-7612-02_love"]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print df
new_df = df.applymap(lambda x: remove_ext(x))
print new_df
```